# Unified opening of .csv and .csv.gz files

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7, I would like to open a file and do some manipulations with it. The problem is that I do not know beforehand if it has a `.csv` or a `.csv.gz` extension. If I knew it was `.csv`, I would do

```
with open(filename, "r") as f_in:
    do something
```

If I knew it was `.csv.gz`, I could say

```
import gzip

with gzip.open(filename, "r") as f_in:
     do something
```

I am curious if there is a way to avoid repetition after figuring out the file extension:

```
def find_ext(filename):
    return filename.split(".")[-1]

ext = find_ext(filename)

if  ext == "csv":
    with open(filename, "r") as f_in:
        do something
else if ext == "gz":
    import gzip
    with gzip.open(filename, "r") as f_in:
         do something
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother looking at the file extension:  Files get renamed or use non-standard variations.

Instead, open the raw file and examine the header.  If it begins with two `32-bit` words `0x00088b1f` and `0`, it is a `gzip` file.

```
import struct

f = open(filename, 'rb')
v = f.read(8)
v1 = struct.unpack('I', v)[0]
v2 = struct.unpack('I', v)[1]
if v1 == 0x00088b1f  and  v2 == 0:
     # it is gzip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import gzip
import mimetypes

smart_open = lambda fn: {"gzip": gzip.open(fn)}.get(mimetypes.guess_type(fn)[1], open(fn))

# usage:
f = smart_open("test.csv.gz")
f = smart_open("test.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since different libraries are used for different cases the check of the extension is required. But one can go with construction like:

```
try:
    ...
except AnError:
    ...
else:
    ...
finally:
    ...
```

Anyway, one (if/else) or another (try/finally) type of construction is necessary since a file opening process is not the same for different cases.

To avoid repetition use such approach (it is pseudocode):

```
def readcsv(file):
    ...

def readgzip(file):
    ...

if csv:
    readcsv(file)
elif gzip:
    readgzip(file)
```